# FileProvider - Open File from Download Directory

Tags: android, download, directory, android-download-manager, android-fileprovider

I can't open any file from Download Folder.

I can download a file and save in Download Folder with this:

```
   DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDescription(descricao);
    request.setTitle(titulo);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nome);

    enq = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

After this, my file is correct saved at Directory Folder: Android >> Internal Shared Storage >> Download.
***This path I see manually opening the device's hd in ubuntu. As the image shows the path.
[Android HD by ubuntu folder - see the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l4MI.png)

And I try open this file with this:

```
downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enq);
                    Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);
                    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if(DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                            String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                            if (uriString.substring(0, 7).matches("file://")) {
                                uriString =  uriString.substring(7);
                            }

                            File file = new File(uriString);

                            Uri uriFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file);
                            String mimetype = "application/pdf";
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            myIntent.setDataAndType(uriFile, mimetype);

                            Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Choose Pdf Application");
                            startActivity(intentChooser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        getContext().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

I declare my file provider in manifest with this:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

and with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="Download" path="Download/"/>
</paths>
```

But when I click the button to download I receive this message: "This file coud be not accessed. Check the location or the network and try again."

Resuming:

1 - The file is downloaded and saved at the directory folder.

2 - The intent is started, but the file is not openned.

3 - Debug mode give me this at "new File(urlString)": "urlString=/storage/emulated/0/Download/name.pdf"

4 - At "FileProvider.getUriFromFile..." debug mode have this:

"uriFile = content://com.example.android.parlamentaresapp.fileprovider/Download/name.pdf"

Thank you.

Comment: `Android >> Internal Shared Storage >> Download.`. That is not a file system path that you could use in your code. Please provide the actual full path.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on the `Intent` that you use with `startActivity()` and the `FileProvider` `Uri`. Without that, the activity has no rights to access your content.

Comment: Important: The file name of file can't have spaces, use: "file-one.txt" and not "file one.txt"

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 101);

i used this code for open file manager in android when i select image from image directory its work properly and i convert it into file and send to server same as audio and video directory,but when i select something from downloads directory or recent files then i did not convert it into file its throw a exception.

Comment: @VishnuSaini; I do not know what you mean by "convert it into file". And, I do know what the exception is. I recommend that you ask a new Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing your code, the full stack trace of the crash, and other details about your situation.